# Im installing hardwood floor, and the mositure level readings are staying divergent between flooring and subfloor, what should i do?

Tags: hardwood-floor

I've watched some you tube videos, and bought a $100 wood moisture reader. Apparently my birch hardwood (which currently reads 6%) should be within 2% of the moisture level of my subfloor (currently sitting at 12%) in order to proceed with my naildown installation. However after a couple days, nothing is changing. Any ideas what could be the reason?

Comment: @EdBeal - it look slike the OP has the opposite problem - his new flooring is *too dry* relative to his sub-floor.

Comment: Mis-read that one, I have always had to sticker and let it dry. deleted+

Answer (score 1):

It will take a week at least to get the moisture to move the the direction it needs to go. Be patient it will acclimate.

Some meters have an adjustable scale for hardwoods, softwoods and plywood, etc., make sure the difference is not because of a calibration from one type of wood to another.

Comment: Ok, I guess I just assumed that after a couple days I would see 0.5-1% change in moisture level.

Comment: Still no change. I talked to manufacturer and plywood uses the same setting as my birch. Shouldn't the reading change at least .5% in 4 days?

Comment: I would expect it to have changed a little by now. It is trying to defy the laws of physics. In times where the flooring has to go down in a short time frame, as in only a short time to let it acclimated, it is stickered as mentioned by Ed Beal. In my experience it takes 2 weeks to get wood acclimated when there is too much humidity. A week to get it to start moving, and another week to get it there.

Comment: Update - the hardwood is all still at 6%. The subfloor is at 6% around the heating vent, and still at 11% on the opposite side of the room. I've been running fans all day for a week too. How patient should I be? Shouldnt the underlayment isolate the subfloor from the hardwood anyways

Comment: It has been 3 weeks the wood will be acclimated by now. Something must be up with the moisture meter, needing an adjustment somewhere, whether it be in the meter or how deep the probes go into the wood or calibration from one specie to the other. I know the plywood producer said this or that, but the moisture meter instructions will be the rule to follow. There is usually a correction made for solid wood to plywood. One last thought, is your crawlspace wet? that will raise the moisture level and not let it go down....

Comment: Could there be a moisture issue that is causing the subfloor to stay more moist?